# export hash array to csv file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, export-to-csv

My objective is to transform a hash array to a csv file.
This is my controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.csv { send_data @comsumptions.to_csv }
end
```

@comsumptions is a hash array:

```
[{"x"=>76,
  "y"=>"example",
  "z"=>2015,
  "consumption"=>#<BigDecimal:7fea4a1cadb8,'0.5382857142E4',18(27)>},
 {"x"=>76,
  "y"=>"example2",
  "z"=>2015,
  "consumption"=>#<BigDecimal:7fea4a1ca7c8,'0.5437E4',9(27)>},(..)
```

I want to create a CSV file with 2 specific columns, "consumption" and "z".
When I did this with these 3 lines comment the output is a file with all the @consumptions. How can I select these 2 columns and transform in a cv file?

```
def self.to_csv
    CSV.generate(headers: true ) do |csv|
      #csv << column_names
      #all.each do |product|
      #  csv << product.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your feedback, I think the best way here is creating a csv view file in your views. For example, if your html file is `comsumptions.html.erb`, then your csv view file should be `comsumptions.csv.ruby`

```
# comsumptions.csv.ruby
require 'csv'

CSV.generate do |csv|
  csv << ['consumption', 'z']
  @comsumptions.each do |c|
    csv << [ c['consumption'].to_s, c['z'] ]
  end
end
```

And we need to change the controller too. Remove `respond_to` part or modify it as follows

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.csv 
end
```

I already tested on my localhost, and this should work!

Comment: Don't work,The csv file output is the @comsumption. Output: `"{""x""=>76, ""y""=>""example"", ""z""=>2015,""consumption""=>#<BigDecimal:7fea43610140,'0.5382857142E4',18(27)>}","{""x""=>76 (..)`

Comment: I removed the part `headers: true` because the first line `csv << ['consumption', 'z']` will write the header.

Comment: same output nothing change :/ How is possible?

Comment: Did you restart your server? My output absolutely doesn't have x, y

Comment: Maybe I missed something. Just to ensure: where do you put your `self.to_csv` method? And `Consumption` is a model?

Comment: Yes I restart the server. def self.to_csv is a function in a model Installation.
 Consumption is not a model is a result of a Stored Procedure.

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer. I'm not sure whether we need to change the controller. But anyway, please try it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'csv'

@comsumptions =
[{"x"=>76,
  "y"=>"example",
  "z"=>2015},
 {"x"=>76,
  "y"=>"example2",
  "z"=>2015}]

class << @comsumptions
  def to_csv (*keys)
    keys = first.keys if keys.empty?
    CSV.generate(headers: keys, write_headers: true) do |csv|
      each do |e|
        csv << e.values_at(*keys)
      end
    end
  end
end

p @comsumptions.to_csv("x","y")
p @comsumptions.to_csv()
```

This solution heavily inspired from the one from Van Huy works fine for any array oh hashes as long as the hashes have all the same keys, undefined behaviour to be expected otherwise

What's not clear to me is where do you put the `def self.to_csv` method, inside the controller? That is wrong. What you want to do is either augment the `@consumptions` object, augment the `Array` class, or define a method in the controller. My example does augment the `@consumptions` object, you can put all that stuff inside the controller method and it should work.

Comment: I put your class << @comsumptions in the controller, when I run the code I got a error in `format.csv { send_data @comsumption.to_csv("x","y") }`. The error description: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)